# How can I use a relative cell reference in native excel to feel back 25 rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say for instance I have a value in  A27 that has satisfied and IF clause. Now I want to take the Summation from it's cell A27, and feel back 25 rows, so in this case to A2

I don't typically work in native excel so excuse the question if it's rather ignorant. This clearly didn't work but might show you what I'm trying to achieve:

```
 =IF(D32-25>$D$6,SUM(A27:A27-25),BLAH)
```

That second A27 would ultimately be A2. Am I going about this the wrong way? Either way it's greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The [OFFSET function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/offset-function-HA102752910.aspx) allows you to move the active cell and optionally shape it.

`=IF(D32-25>$D$6, SUM(OFFSET(A27,-25,0,25,1)), "blah")`

Make sure that you are getting the correct range, It is possible that you want to offset up -26 cells and `SUM` the next 25.